# Custom popup/login screen when people connect to wifi network

Tags: apache, wifi

I have a belkin router. When people connect to this via wifi to access the internet I want to display a custom popup window similar to when you go to a coffee shop and connect to free public wifi connections.

How does one go about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.hotspotsystem.com/hotspot-software

You'll also require a compatible router, a router which can be flashed with the DD-WRT custom firmware will do the job.